# Access SQL sorting the data with latest date

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT  distinct  a.Project_Manager, a.Project_ID, a.Topic,  a.Stage,
a.Presentation_Date, a.Presentation_Notes,  a.Presentation_Status,  a.Category,
a.Postponed_Reason,  a.Postponed_Manager
FROM GSC_Presentation_Info  a
inner join   (
           SELECT Project_ID as Project_ID, MAX(Presentation_Date) as
           Max_Presentation_Date
           from GSC_Presentation_Info 
           group by  Project_ID   
              )  b
ON   a.Project_ID = b.Project_ID
and  a.Presentation_Date = b.Max_Presentation_Date
```

I really want to hide the records which are not linked with a recent presentation date. But Access keeps showing me the circular reference caused by alias `Project_ID` in query definition's `SELECT` list. I don't really know how to fix that.

Tried this code:

```
SELECT Max(GSC_Presentation_Info.Presentation_Date) AS MaxOfPresentation_Date1, GSC_Presentation_Info.Project_ID AS Project_ID
FROM GSC_Presentation_Info
GROUP BY GSC_Presentation_Info.Project_ID;
```

Works for me, but I need other columns as well. But once I add them in within the group function, they will show the duplicate right away.

Also tried with this code  but it shows duplicates too:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM GSC_Presentation_Info GPI,  
     (SELECT Max(GSC_Presentation_Info.Presentation_Date) AS MaxOfPresentation_Date, GSC_Presentation_Info.Project_ID
     FROM GSC_Presentation_Info
     GROUP BY GSC_Presentation_Info.Project_ID) MVV
    WHERE  GPI.Presentation_Date = MVV.Presentation_Date 
    AND GPI.Project_ID = MVV.Project_ID;
```

Comment: This is a standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.  What do you mean access shows you the "circular reference"?  Could we get sample starting data and desired results?  You likely don't need `DISTINCT`, as hopefully at least a subset of those columns is unique anyways.  (Also, please learn how to format queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the alias for your Project_ID column - Access won't let you use an alias name that already exists as a column name or another alias name.

```
...inner join   (
           SELECT Project_ID, MAX(Presentation_Date) as
           Max_Presentation_Date
           from GSC_Presentation_Info 
           group by  Project_ID   
           )  b
...
```

Comment: [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97526 "ACC: “Circular Reference Caused by Alias” Error Message") appears to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT Project_Manager, Project_ID, Topic,  Stage, Presentation_Date, Presentation_Notes,  Presentation_Status,  Category,  Postponed_Reason,  Postponed_Manager
FROM GSC_Presentation_Info

group by Project_ID
order by Presentation_Date desc
limit 5`

This will produce the latest 5 dates results. If you want more than that just increase limit.

Comment: thanks!! but the ID already linked to several records. i wanna be like  the recored linked with one id and with the latest Presentation date

Comment: i also tried with ur code, the access saying syntax error in order by clause :( Please help

Comment: have you changed the presentation name from lowercase to upper case.

Comment: yeah i cope paste the code to sql , but it still saying the same error as before

Comment: ... and there's no reason to use `LIMIT` here, either.  Why would you think that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work with RANK() function as well.
I am using Teradata SQL. The synatx might be slightly different for us.

The table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE stack_test 
(
 Project_ID VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC,
 Project_Manager VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC,
 Presentation_Date DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'
)
PRIMARY KEY stack_test_pk ( Project_ID ,Presentation_Date );
```

Records I Inserted:

```
INSERT INTO stack_test ('123','Adam','2014-05-01');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('123','Adam','2014-05-02');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('123','Adam','2014-05-03');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('234','Leveen','2014-05-03');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('345','Sang','2014-03-01');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('345','Sang','2014-03-02');
INSERT INTO stack_test ('678','Liam','2014-05-19');
```

SELECT Statement that use:

```
SELECT 
Project_Manager, 
Project_ID,
Presentation_Date,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Project_ID ORDER BY Presentation_Date DESC) presen_rank
FROM stack_test 
QUALIFY presen_rank = 1;
```

Result that I got:

```
Project_Manager       Project_ID  Presentation_Date  presen_rank
--------------------  ----------  -----------------  -----------
Adam                  123                2014-05-03            1
Leveen                234                2014-05-03            1
Sang                  345                2014-03-02            1
Liam                  678                2014-05-19            1
```

Hope this works for you too.

Since RANK() isn't working for you. Try the following:

```
SELECT y.Project_Manager, y.Project_ID,y.Presentation_Date
FROM (
        SELECT
            Project_ID,
            MAX(Presentation_Date) AS Presentation_Date
        FROM stack_test 
        GROUP BY Project_ID
     ) x
INNER JOIN stack_test y ON (y.Project_ID = x.Project_ID AND y.Presentation_Date =  x.Presentation_Date)
GROUP BY y.Project_Manager, y.Project_ID,y.Presentation_Date;
```

This gives the result as follows.

```
Project_Manager       Project_ID  Presentation_Date
--------------------  ----------  -----------------
Liam                  678                2014-05-19
Sang                  345                2014-03-02
Adam                  123                2014-05-03
Leveen                234                2014-05-03
```

Comment: wow that's exactly the result i wanna get!!! but the code doesnt work for the access. saying "syntax error missing operator in query expression rank() over (partition by project id order by presentation_date desc) presen_rank"

Comment: Can you try now? I have edited to make it compatible.

Comment: emm i change the stack_test into GSC_Presentation_Info but the access saying"circular reference caused by alias Presentation_Date in the query definition's SELECT list"

Comment: Yes, it turns out sub-query is not allowed in MS Access SQL. I am trying to figure something out, will let you know.

Comment: @TinaQiaotianYan Did you try adding AS in front of the derived table x? Because according to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/is-it-possible-to-join-derived-tables-to-actual-in-access-2007  the sub-query portion should be working.

Comment: Try adding `AS` before the `x` and before the `y` in your table/subquery alias, assuming there are no other syntax errors.

Comment: @haldar55 nope  access saying circular reference caused by alias Presentation_Date in the query definition'S SELECT list

Comment: Then maybe someone with MS Acess expirience will be a better guide.